# Ошибка при запуске php с локального сервера (OOП, namespace)

Tags: php

Изучаю ООП по видео и 
там автор использует редактор PhPStorm, у меня же Sublime Text3 и при запуске index.php с локального сервера в браузере появляется такая ошибка:

> "Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script in W:\domains\integrity.ru\app\App.php on line 3"

Причем, если запустить отдельно `$app = new liw\core\App();`, то все работает. Браузер выдает строку с текстом. Что не так со вторым файлом App.php-php, ведь они почти идентичны и с одинаковым названием App? Один находится в папке: vendor\liw\core\App.php, другой в app\App.php

Файл: app\App.php

```
<?php

namespace app;

class App

{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'Я нахожусь в пакете app';
    }
}
```

Файл: vendor\liw\core\App.php

```
<?php

namespace liw\core;

class App

{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'Я нахожусь в пакете liw/core';
    }
}
```

Файл: index.php

```
<?php

require '../vendor/liw/core/App.php';

require '../app/App.php';


$app = new liw\core\App();

echo '<br>';

$app2 = new app\App();
```

Answer (score 0):

https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.definition.php

```
<html>
<?php
namespace MyProject; // fatal error - объявление пространства имен должно быть первым выражением в скрипте
?>
```

все echo должны быть после объявления пространств имён.

Answer (score 0):

Там может стоять невидимый пробел перед `<?php`. Помог перенос всего кода на новый файл